# Spring Security , access="ROLE_ADMIN" Vs access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In Spring Security:

```
<sec:http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http>
```

in this line `<intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />`

What is difference meaning if I write:

`<intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />`

or:

`<intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Spring Security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#el-common-built-in) states:

> **hasRole([role])**: Returns true if the current principal has the
>   specified `role`
>
> **hasAnyRole([role1,role2])**: Returns true if the current principal has any of the supplied roles (given as a comma-separated list of strings).

Also, on `access` attribute, [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-intercept-url-attributes) states:

> **access**: Lists the access attributes which will be stored in the
>   `FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource` for the defined URL
>   pattern/method combination. This should be a comma-separated list of
>   the security configuration attributes (**such as role names**).

But in your case, you're passing a single element list to the `hasAnyRole`, So:

> access="ROLE_ADMIN" Vs access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')

`hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')` and `hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')` are identical and both means that the current principal should have the `ROLE_ADMIN` authority.

(a **"principal"** generally means a user, device or some other system which can perform an action in your application).